# Concat and/or merge objects in two generic lists

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

i need help with this problem...
I have two lists of same objects "SearchResult", this object has an id attribute and a score attribute.
In both list can exist the same id, but with different score, so i need to create a new List that combines same id's but the score must be the sum of both scores and finally, the list get ordered by that final score.
How can i do that?
I search for a linq query, but i cant find any solution.

I hope you can help me, thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you might want something like:

```
var summed = results1.Concat(results2)
                     .GroupBy(r => r.Id)
                     .Select(g => new SearchResult { 
                                Id = g.Key, 
                                Score = g.Sum(x => x.Score)
                             });
```

Comment: Oh my god! You answer the question before asking the question dude!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Union` method from link. Example:

```
var mergedList = firstList.Union(secondList);
```